# How do you tell direction and what's positive or negative in wave functions?

Tags: waves

$$y = 1.00 \sin(5x − 2t)$$

So if I'm given $y(x,t)$, it's pretty clear what the amplitude, angular frequency and $k$ value appear to be. However, when I'm doing homework problems, the angular frequency seems to be positive. Is it always supposed to be positive? Is it always going in the positive $x$-direction?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is convention to write frequency positive. Luckily, you can use that $\sin(x) = - \sin(-x)$ to help you do that here. Then you just get a negative amplitude.

The argument becomes $2t-5k$, so now it should be clear the wave is going in the positive x-direction.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. So how do you even make it negative?